# Include a variable inside a INPUT statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a input statement with a variable inside.
It is a script to get multiple names from the user input

```
x = int(input("Numbers of names that'll be written: "))

for count in range(x):
    name = str(input("Insert the name number {}".format(count))) # <- This works but it's not what i want to achieve, since i don't know how to add a text after the .format
    # name = str(input("Insert the ",count,"st name: )) <- This doesn't work
```

I expect the output:

```
Insert the 1st name; Insert the 2nd name; Insert the 3nd name;
```

Comment: `{}` doesn't have to be at the end of string - `"Insert  {} name".format(cont)`

Comment: `cont` should probably be `count`, otherwise `NameError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i don't know how to add a text after the .format

Just like you have text before the `{}`, you can have text after it.

```
str(input("Insert the name number {}, whatever should come after 'cont'".format(cont)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the ordinal suffix, there may be an easiest (ie. more optimal) way to get it but that's a start:

```
def numberth(num: int):
    val = str(num)
    if val.endswith('1'):
        return val + 'st'
    if val.endswith('2'):
        return val + 'nd'
    if val.endswith('3'):
        return val + 'rd'
    return val + 'th'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an answer to this question in 2022... here's a method that works with both `print` and `input`. It is called *format string literals* or *f-strings*:

```
variable_x = input(f"begin string {variable_1} continue string {variable_2} continue string {variable_3} end of string")
```

Or if you need to specify `int` or `float` for your input, it would look like this:

```
variable_x = int(input(f"begin string {variable_1} continue string {variable_2} continue string {variable_3} end of string"))
```

And it looks the same for `print`:

```
print(f"begin string {variable_1} continue string {variable_2} continue string {variable_3} continue string {variable_x} end of string"))
```